# What factors cause the harmonic distortion in ADC at high signal amplitudes?

Tags: adc, noise, harmonics

I have been studying about the ADC's SNR vs amplitude relation. A sample curve is shown below:

[image]

I am interested in the region rounded (orange) of the gray curve. At that region, we expect to see harmonics in the spectrum and thus define the SFDR.

[image]

I found that at that region, there are 2 effects happening:

1. Increase in noise floor (due to Jitter) (green arrow)
2. Harmonic distortions (due to Non-Linearities) (magenta rounded)

I am interested in (2). I am trying to understand what kind of non-linearities causes these harmonic distortion. I am aware of effects like feedback DAC mismatch, amplifier saturation - but they generalize to one concept - **saturation**. (Of course this non-linearity sometimes is used in diode mixers for frequency conversion)

Is there some different non-linearity which causes these harmonic spurs (magenta rounded)?

Comment: Could you specify what kind of ADC you are talking about?...Oversampled or nyquist (SAR or any other).

Comment: @sarthak Sure. The above SNR vs amplitude curve corresponds to Oversampled sigma delta ADC. But I hope this effect is something absolute to time-discrete systems.

Comment: No. It’s not. Saturation is a different phenomena. Please edit your question specifying the type, and order, of ADC the curve comes from.

Comment: At large voltage swings, the very junction_capacitances, which are non-linear, will demand **DIFFERENT** amounts of charge, and cause the switch-cap filters and summers and comparators to have non-linearities.